# how to insert multiple row in single query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a variable that holds multiple data, and I want to insert this multiple data into PostgreSQL database using a single query.

the field on my table is this: `stud_tbl(id,fname,lname)`

and this is the variable that holds multiple data;

```
variable = (123,ron,lum),(234,nald,bay),(345,rol,lumz)
```

my query:

```
str = "insert into stud_tbl values ('" & variable & "')"
```

when I execute my query their was an error and I can't identify the error.

Comment: You quote the entire variable. Instead you should only quote the text values inside the variable.

Comment: how to quote the value inside the variable sir?

Comment: Which Programming language you're using ?

Comment: the scenario goes like this,, i select that data into different table, concat all selected data and pass to a variable "variable" thats why the data is like ths (123,ron,lum),(234,nald,bay),(345,rol,lumz), so my problem is cant save those data into table "stud_tbl" with a single query

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Patrick's comment:

```
variable = "(123,'ron','lum'),(234,'nald','bay'),(345,'rol','lumz')"
```

the query:

```
str = "insert into stud_tbl values " & variable
```

Though the usual warnings ([How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)) about this not being best practice apply.

Answer (score -1):

Value of your variable should be enclosed with quotation marks

```
variable = "(123,ron,lum),(234,nald,bay),(345,rol,lumz)"
```